# WPF two-way binding: how do I update a TextBox with a formatted version of the value it just set?

Tags: wpf, binding, two-way-binding

I have a class, called `DateField`, that has a string `Value` property.  If you set this property to a string that can be parsed into a valid date, the property setter sets `Value` to the properly formatted date, e.g.:

```
    private string _Value;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _Value)
            {
                return;
            }
            object result;
            if (TryParse(value, out result))
            {
                _Value = Format(result);
            }
            else
            {
                _Value = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
```

I create a TextBox that's bound to this field:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:DateField}">
        <TextBox                                         
                IsTabStop="True"
                Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When I enter, say, `"010109"` into this field and tab out of it, the `Binding` appropriately sets the `Value` property to this string.  The property setter runs, `_Value` gets correctly set to `"01/01/2009"` (the `TryParse` implementation in this class is a little more catholic in what it accepts than `DateTime.TryParse` is), and the `PropertyChanged` event gets raised.  I know this last bit is happening because another object that's subscribed to the list gets updated.

But the `TextBox` doesn't.  Why not?  I've set `Value`, I've raised `PropertyChanged`; what more do I need to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and implement both the `Convert` and the `ConvertBack` methods

Comment: Done; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this working properly, but I'm not entirely happy with how I've done it.

The typical pattern for using a `ValueConverter` is that the `ConvertBack` should return the converted value if parsing succeeded, and `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` if it failed.  I can't do that.  If I do that, the bound `Value` property doesn't get set.  So the value doesn't get validated, and no validation error doesn't shows up in the UI.

What I've done instead is implemented a `DateValueConverter` class whose `ConvertBack` method returns either the parsed `DateTime`, or the string that it unsuccessfully tried to convert.  The `Value` property in my `DateTimeField` class (actually, in the `Field` class it's derived from) looks like this:

```
public object Value
{
    get
    {
        return _Value;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == _Value)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Validate(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        _Value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Value");
    }
}
```

The `Validate` method basically just looks at the type of the value being passed in:  if it's a `DateTime`, then it's valid; if it's a string, it's not.

I'm not happy with this because it seems like a `ValueConverter` shouldn't convert a value into two different types.  It feels like a hack.  But maybe it's okay.  I need to think about this some more.